# Listing of Categories in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to list categories according to attached image, but didn't get any success, please help me if anyone has any idea. South, East and North will be in loop, so i can add any other at anytime, I am new in php or Wordpress so need your help [image]

```
 <?php $args = array('orderby' => 'id', 'hide_empty'=> 0, 'child_of' => 1); $categories = get_categories($args); foreach ($categories as $cat) { $background_color = get_option('cat_background_color'.$cat->term_id); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 boxshadow categorylisting padd0 Box1">
  <div class="Catheading cat1" style="background-color: #<?php echo  $background_color; ?>;"> <span class="config"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" alt="" /></span>
    <h3><?php echo $cat->name ?></h3>
  </div>
    <div class="catlist">
    <ul>
      <?php   $args2= array("orderby"=>'id', "category" => $cat->cat_ID); // Get Post from each Sub-Category
    $posts_in_category = get_posts($args2);
    foreach($posts_in_category as $current_post) {

        ?>
      <li type='none' ><a href="<?=$current_post->guid;?>">
        <?=''.$current_post->post_title;?>
        </a></li>
      <?php
    } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: Please check i replied